# how can get unique url for each post in node js

Tags: node.js

How to create deep links just like share Facebook post or profile URL I only know how to create a restful API with express i make post request to get all posts from the database how to get a unique URL for each post to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to create a route with parameter :

```
{ path: 'post/:id',      component: PostComponent }
```